# Calling Internal Functions in a Shared Library

Tags: compilation, shared-libraries, elf, glibc, dynamic-linking

I want to call an **unexported** function in `glibc`. Precisely, I want to call `ptmalloc_init()`. The problem is that the symbol is **not** exported. I have access to the `glibc` source code. Therefore, I added a function called `ptmalloc_init_caller()` in `glibc` source code and compiled the library. But again I can not see anything in the `nm -D` output and, as a consequence, can **not** call the added function *from outside*. Is there something *special* about building `glibc` that is omitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `ptmalloc_init` function non-`static` and add it to `malloc/Versions`, e.g. under the `GLIBC_PRIVATE` section. Then it will be exported. Without the change to `malloc/Versions`, the function will not be mentioned in the generated version script (see `libc.map` in the build tree), and its symbol will have hidden visibility.